# SQL server - inserting a string with a single quotation mark

Tags: c#, sql-server, dml

I iterate over an external source and get a list of strings. I then insert them into the DB using:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Where commandString is an insert into command. i.e.

```
insert into MyTable values (1, "Frog")
```

Sometimes the string contains ' or " or \ and the insert fails.
Is there an elegant way to solve this (i.e. @"" or similar)?

Comment: Using parametrized queries?

Answer (score 2):

Parameters.

```
insert into MyTable values (@id, @name)
```

And

```
int id = 1;
string name = "Fred";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now `name` can have any number of quotes and it'll work fine. More importantly it is now safe from sql injection.

Tools like "dapper" (freely available on NuGet) make this easier:

```
int id = 1;
string name = "Fred";
connection.Execute("insert into MyTable values (@id, @name)",
    new { id, name });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using parameterized queries. This will allow you insert the data no matter the content and also help you avoid possible future SQL injection.

http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/parameterized-query-and-sql-injection-attacks/